# Where can I find good documentation for templates in BibDesk?

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk

I want a simple way to export a bibliography to MS word format.  I started by learning about bibtex, but this only helps with exporting to pdfs.  I then found out about bibdesk, which has a nice gui, and customizable templates. HOWEVER, the documentation for this is completely opaque.  Take for example, this link:https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_93.html#SEC166, and this one at the bottom of the first one: https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/manual/BibDeskHelp_94.html#SEC179

The description field for each entry is blank, leaving me in the dark! Is there a simple, well written, one-stop documentation site for learning bibdesk templates? What background information should I learn to make the bibdesk export template documentation less opaque?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, see if BibDesk's Help menu gives you a more up-to-date version of the documentation; the website has a static snapshot of it, and it may be fairly old.

Having said that, the BibDesk wiki is probably the best resource for this: https://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Templates/

I'd recommend downloading a few templates to study by example. Unfortunately, I think most of those keys have been requested by users, and it's sort of grown organically over the years. Most of them you can probably figure out from context after looking at some examples, and you might be able to add documentation to the wiki.